# How to remove all grid lines except left Y axis and bottom X axis using Charts ios?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

In my app I'm using the iOS-Charts framework, and I figured out how to remove the grid (vertical and horizontal) by using:

```
barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false 
barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

However, I still want to have left side Y axis and bottom X axis.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
//to hide x , y indicator axis - labels
yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
  
    
//to hide x , y indicator axis - lines
yAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    
//to hide x , y indicator axis - grid lines
yAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
yAxis.gridLineWidth = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried every solution available for none worked for me. Seems like from Swift 4 you can not disable grid lines totally. One solution you have though is making the grid lines clear color so that they are not visible.

```
chartView.xAxis.gridColor = .clear
chartView.leftAxis.gridColor = .clear
chartView.rightAxis.gridColor = .clear
```

Answer (score -2):

To Enable x and y axis alone

```
yourView.leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = true
yourView.rightAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = true
```